# How to download the latest Android SDK packages without Android Studio and sdkmanager?

Tags: android

I would like to download the latest Android SDK packages without `Android Studio` and `sdkmanager`.

I only need these 4 packages:

- `SDK`
- `SDK Platform`
- `SDK Build Tools`
- `SDK Platform Tools`

From https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/build-tools I can get:

- `SDK Build Tools` https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r34-linux.zip

From https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools I can get:

- `SDK Platform Tools` https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r34.0.4-linux.zip

But I am unable to get:

- `SDK`
- `SDK Platform`

I know these old packages:

- `SDK` https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
- `SDK Platform` https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-16_r05.zip

From https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-12.xml I can get:

- `SDK Platform` https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-22_r02.zip

But how to get the latest `SDK` and `SDK Platform` packages please?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: Why don't you lookup the URLs here: https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Thanks @Robert very useful because now I can get a recent SDK Platform https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-33_r02.zip . However, it is not the latest if I compare to what is said here: https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platforms . Also, I don't find the SDK on this website. I only see, SDK Platform, SDK Build Tools and SDK Platform Tools. Moreover, I am more interested in a solution to find these packages without using a third-party website like this one.

Comment: May be because there is no "SDK" package. Not sure what it should contain, looking at my Android SDK file structure all the directories I see are separate packages so I don't see what could be contained in what you call "SDK".

Comment: @Robert Indeed, I have tried to build my project without the ```SDK``` package and it works. So, the ```SDK``` package is not necessary. Moreover, I have tried without the ```SDK Platform Tools``` package and it works too! So, I only need the ```SDK Build Tools``` package (for ```dx``` and ```aapt```) and the ```SDK Platform``` package (for ```android.jar```).

Comment: Note that dx and aapt are deprecated so they might be removed in future releases. Successors are R8 and aapt2.

Comment: @Robet Indeed. I am planning to use ```d8``` and ```aapt2``` instead of ```dx``` and ```aapt``` to build my project.